# How can I change the accelerate key in Need for Speed: Hot Pursuit?

Tags: need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

I am trying to change the key controls of *Need for Speed: Hot Pursuit* on Windows 7, but when I go to: *Settings* → *Gameplay Settings* → *Controls*, and I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to change the key configuration, it says "volume down":

[image: screenshot of settings described above]

I don't have any idea what key that corresponds to.

I have a Lenovo Y470 laptop, which has a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, and if you press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>, it reduces the volume. Initially, I thought maybe this was what it was referring to, but it doesn't work.

How can I use the accelerate control? What button does this correspond to?

Comment: Does your computer have a touch panel at the top? Looking at a picture of it, I can see little dimples there, but I can't tell what they're for.

Comment: @SaintWacko No there is no touch panel ( at top ). Do you have any idea why it is showing volume down? BTW, as 'Volume down' is pressed i can accelerate without pressing any key.

Comment: Hm. I thought maybe it was constantly sending a volume down signal. Can you turn your volume up, or is it constantly being turned down?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but had button Home instead of Volume Up. I tried pressing fn + home and home a few times and then it fixed itself and I could switch to WASD.

Answer (score -2):

I was having this problem until I disabled the webcam from device manager, then it worked for me.